# How to get data of month without error throw?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some stock data collected day by day. These data are store in a csv file.
But some stock may not have trade data on some day.

Data looks like below:
| stock_code | trade_date| open | close | high | low |
| ---------- | --- | --- | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: |
| sh6000001  | 2022-01-06 | 1.1| 1.09| 1.21| 0.99|
| sh6000001  | 2022-03-01 | 1.5| 1.03| 1.21| 0.99|

```py
import pandas as pd

stock = pd.read_csv(stock_csv_file, parse_dates=['trade_date'], encoding='gbk')
stock.set_index(keys=['trade_date'], drop=False, inplace=True)

# below line should get all these trade data of given month
print(stock['2022-02'])
```

But above code `stock['2022-02']` may raise Error due to there is NO trade data happened on given month '2022-02'. I have to catch the Error. But I want to get an empty DataFrame just with column definition.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/i521084/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '2022-02'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/i521084/dev/codes/my/python/quant_class/stock_data/program/py/experimental/ting_pai.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(df['2022-02'])
  File "/Users/i521084/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/i521084/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '2022-02'
```

Which function can meet my requirement?

Comment: try stock[stock.index=='2022-02'] . If you do not wanna write this all the time, write a function for it such as : def search(df, date):
    print (df[df.index==date]) ; and use search(stock, '2022-02') in the future.

Comment: I am afraid it not work. It will not return any data. Even there is data in given month.

Comment: I think you gott give me a slice of that dataframe so that I can test on it. Because it does work on my dataframe with a date column. Unless, your ['trade_date'] column includes to date but you are searching with just with year and date, because that is a different problem.

Comment: `df[pd.to_datetime(df['trade_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m') == '2022-02']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the conversation with you within the comments and on rereading the question, I believe I get your goals.

Let's say you have a column with dates and within the  same row are different data for stock, I imagine. But since you did not give us a dummy dataset to test it on, so here's a dummy from some other problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date1": ["2019-01-11", "2019-02-12", "2019-03-11", "2020-01-10", "2020-02-10", "2020-03-15"],
                   "date2": ["2019-01-12", "2019-02-20", "2019-03-19", "2020-01-09", "2021-02-10", "2021-03-15"],
                   "name_col": ["A","A","A","B","B","B"],
                   "age_col":[10,15,20,12,13,16]})

       date1       date2 name_col  age_col
0 2019-01-11  2019-01-12        A       10
1 2019-02-12  2019-02-20        A       15
2 2019-03-11  2019-03-19        A       20
3 2020-01-10  2020-01-09        B       12
4 2020-02-10  2021-02-10        B       13
5 2020-03-15  2021-03-15        B       16
```

I will focus on the "date1" column as our concerned one, and we will search within it. But please be noted that here the date format is already in Pandas default format. If it is not the same case for you, change the data format using pd.to_datetime first.

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], format=#yours#)
```

Now you want search within the dataset using only the month, so if there is more than one day of data in the column, you want them all. So, you want the "search term" with the "year-month" of the column. Instead of keeping it in a different column, we will just match it.

```
df["date1"].dt.to_period('M')
0    2019-01
1    2019-02
2    2019-03
3    2020-01
4    2020-02
5    2020-03
Name: date1, dtype: period[M]

df["date1"].dt.to_period('M')=="2019-01"
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: date1, dtype: bool
```

Now you can write it in a funciton.

```
def search(df, col, date):
    return (df[df[col].dt.to_period('M')==date])

search(df, "date1", "2019-01")
       date1       date2 name_col  age_col
0 2019-01-11  2019-01-12        A       10
```

Let's check for a value that is not in the column, for example yours "2022-02".

```
search(df, "date1", "2022-02")
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date1, date2, name_col, age_col]
Index: []
```

Try to apply this but tweaking where necessary, please let me know if it does not fit your problem.

Also always consider adding a dummy dataset people can import into their environment easily, so that you can have more people joining. Not just people like me who are bored at their cubicle.

Comment: The answer is correct. It works as my expectation. Thanks for so quick and detail answer.